# Scatter plot with two nominal variables

Tags: powerbi

I have a data set that contains three columns -- `Sample ID` (1 to 100), `Experiment ID`, and `Result` (between 0 to 1).
[image]
I would like to plot a scatter plot, x axis as `Experiment ID`, y axis as `Sample ID`, and the `Result` will be represented by color grade. Demo plot from other programs is given as following. 
[image]

Could you please show me how to plot that in Power BI? Power BI tends to group the `Sample ID` and `Experiment ID`, and choose the details as `Experiment ID` seems not get what I want. Any hint or instruction will be helpful, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scatter chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-visualization-scatter) only accepts numerical values for `X Axis` and `Y Axis`. Therefore, you couldn't put `Experiment ID` in `X Axis`. If you remove the character part of it and change it to `Number` type, the following chart closest to what you want can be achieved:

[image: scatter chart]

With `Result` as `Color saturation`.

However, one problem is that the shape is still too big even the size is set to `0 %`. Not sure if this will be the deal breaker for you to use the scatter chart in Power BI.